# dividing a point cloud to equal size sub-clouds

Tags: algorithm, geometry, point-clouds

I want to find an algorithm that solves the following problem.

Suppose we have a point cloud with N points of dimension m we want to divide the point cloud into sub-clouds where any sub-cloud is larger than or equal to size k and we want to minimize the following:

1. each sub-cloud size is closest as possible to k.
2. the distances between points in each sub-cloud.

any direction for a solution will be great, and implementation in python will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using K-means machine learning algorithm?
I know it's not a perfect solution, as you still need to solve the k-size condition, but it's a good direction.

To solve the issue I would:

1. Choose my k to be something around N / size of sub-cloud (what you called k). I think it has the best chance to success.
2. Each sub-cloud that returned from the algorithm and is smaller than the wanted size- just add its points to the closest sub-cloud that's been created.

Hope it helped you somehow!

Comment: thanks for the replay, I did try K-means didn't work well as I wanted to.